# NSMutableArray Init troubles

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have this method dealing with a couple array that I can't seem to get right.  Something related to the alloc and init.

```
- (void)addBookmark
{
    // Get the user defaults object
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // Load your bookmarks (editable array)
    NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *bookmarksLoaded = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"bookmarks"];
    if (bookmarksLoaded != nil) {
        [bookmarks initWithArray:bookmarksLoaded];
    } else {
        [bookmarks init];
    }

    // Add a bookmark
    NSMutableDictionary *bookmark = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [bookmark setValue:@"value" forKey:@"name"];
    [bookmark setValue:@"value" forKey:@"description"];
    [bookmark setValue:@"value" forKey:@"code"];
    [bookmarks addObject:bookmark];

    // Save your (updated) bookmarks
    [userDefaults setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"bookmarks"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    // Memory cleanup
    [bookmarks release];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right - it is your use of alloc/init. You should only `init` an object once. You want something like this:

```
// Load your bookmarks (editable array)
NSMutableArray *bookmarks = nil; // we'll initialize it later
NSArray *bookmarksLoaded = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"bookmarks"];
if (bookmarksLoaded) { // shortcut for bookmarksLoaded != nil
    bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:bookmarksLoaded];
} else {
    bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

// Add a bookmark
NSMutableDictionary *bookmark = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

If you use `dictionary` instead of `new`, you get an autoreleased object that you don't have to worry about (`new` isn't used in Cocoa). As you have it, you're leaking memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *bookmarksLoaded = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"bookmarks"];
if (bookmarksLoaded != nil) {
    [bookmarks initWithArray:bookmarksLoaded];
} else {
    [bookmarks init];
}
```

The problem with above code is you are initing bookmarks everywhere..Any object in objective C must be inited once..I will rewrite your code as

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarks = nil;
NSArray *bookmarksLoaded = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"bookmarks"];
if (bookmarksLoaded != nil) {
    bookmarks            = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:bookmarksLoaded];
} else {
    bookmarks     =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Also you must release NSMutableDictionary bookmark since you are creating it via new..

```
NSMutableDictionary *bookmark = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[bookmark setValue:@"value" forKey:@"name"];
[bookmark setValue:@"value" forKey:@"description"];
[bookmark setValue:@"value" forKey:@"code"];
[bookmarks addObject:bookmark];
 [bookmark release];
```

Additionally, from the code it is understood that you haven't grasped memory management in iphone yet..To be a successful iOS developer, you must study that first..